# Querying amount of time level spent out of range

Tags: sql, time, limits, aggregates

I have a table with that records the time and level of a tank.

12:00 | 85

12:01 | 77

12:02 | 78

12:03 | 82

12:05 | 79

12:06 | 75

12:07 | 85

etc.

How could you write a query to get the amount of time the tank was below 80 throughout the day?
I am using sql server 2008

Comment: What's the type of the first column?

Comment: Needs more detailed information for a truly correct answer, but the way it looks, if one line represents one minute, and you're always sampling every minute, as a shortcut, couldn't you just count the number of lines where the level is < 80, since 1 line = 1 minute?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need the next time.  Some databases have `lead()` and `lag()` functions.  I'll do this with a correlated subquery -- a more general method.

```
select sum(endTime - Time)
from (select t.*,
             (select min(time) from t t2 where t2.time > t.time
             ) as endTime
      from t
     ) t
where level < 80;
```

One caveat:  date and time functions vary between databases, so the first syntax does not necessary work.  For instance, in SQL Server, it might be:

```
select sum(datediff(ms, Time, endTime))
```